# STL on Visual Studio Express 2010 Vs Linux gcc-4.3.2

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2010, stl, g++

I executed a code on the linux gcc-4.3.2 and on the windows visual studio express 2010.
the execution time for Linux was around 54 seconds , while on the windows system it was around 1207 seconds.

Why is this so ?
The code uses the C++ stl map, set and vector.
The same code when executed on ideone took 9 seconds.

http://ideone.com/MxGogf

Are the stl implementations different ?

To measure time I used the following :

```
int main(){
clock_t tStart = clock();
.
.
printf("\n%.4f\n",float(clock()-tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
}
```

I know this method to measure time is not accurate , but 54 and 1207 are too far apart.

Comment: how did you compile it? Did you try some newer Linux GCC compiler (current version of GCC is 4.8; yours 4.3.2  is really old)?

Comment: Even though its old, it still runs much faster than the VS2010.
But I guess as jalf said, it might be because I am executing it in the debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you're comparing debug builds.
Don't do that.

If you want to know how fast your code is, *compile it with optimizations*.

MSVC++ does *a lot* of additional asserts and debug checks in debug builds.

Comment: I am fairly new to Visual Studio. Can you guide me as to how I can compile using optimisations ? I set the optimisation to "Maximum Speed" in the project settings but the result remains the same. (Or atleast its still not any closer to 54 seconds)
EDIT : It came down to 72 seconds! :)